# Working with Magento - breaking it down

Tags: svn, magento

I have two related questions:

1. Is it possible to break down Magento into manageable, bitesize pieces so

   - my IDE does not have to handle the entire damned project in order to change a line of CSS
   - I don't have to export it all to the server when I want to deploy it?
2. Which bits of Magento, precisely, should you never touch (unless upgrading to a newer version)? For example app/code/core?

As anyone who has worked with Magento, it is a beast of an application. On my development pc, it drains a ton of resources and working with it is like wading through 2 feet of mud.

My current method of working with it is to basically to stick the entire code base in an SVN repository.

When I'm done implementing something, I update a development SVN working copy on the server and test it.

When I'm happy with the changes, I export to a new folder on the server, symlink in local.xml & media folder, then symlink the webserver (Apache) directory to it.

My little system has been effective, yet for the life of me I can't figure out how to make it faster!

I was considering different SVN (or Git) branches or even repos to handle distinct parts of the app, for example app/code/local or skin/frontend/default but can't figure out specifics or even if it's the best way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the sounds of it you may want to consider just keeping app/code/local, app/code/community and the design packages inside your repos if you are wanting to keep things slim, and just maintain the core code of magneto as a separate package.

I've found that Git seems to work better with Magento's large number of files/folders.

If you are using NetBeans for an IDE you can disable the scanning of the project files to build auto completes if you don't need it.  I'm not sure about other IDE's however.

Like you so elegantly put it, Magento can really be a stick in the mud on being overly abstracted. I would recommend looking into an Op code cache (like APC) for the PHP files and to go over your Mysql settings in your local environment to help find and elevate as many bottle necks as you can.

You may also want to consider [Modman](http://code.google.com/p/module-manager/wiki/Tutorial) as well.

Here is a good article on advice and opinions on how to structure your magento projects:

- http://www.aschroder.com/2010/07/structuring-your-magento-project-for-engineering-not-hacking/

Comment: thank you so much, just what I was after. Modman certainly looks interesting.